# How Do I Delete Orphan Kubernetes Pods

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running Kubernetes via [Docker](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/). Following the tutorial I launched an Nginx POD using `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80`. However this seems to create orphaned PODs (without a replication controller). `kubectl get rc` doesn't return anything and `kubectl describe pod nginx-198147104-kqudh` shows **Replication Controllers: none** (kubectl version "v1.2.0+5cb86ee" shows Controllers: ReplicaSet/nginx-198147104 but scaling it to 0 just causes a new Nginx pod to be created, and it can't be deleted).

I would like to be able to delete the Kubernetes managed Nginx container from Docker. I haven't had much luck find out how to delete an orphan pod (without it being recreated...).

**Client Version**: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.4", GitCommit:"65d28d5fd12345592405714c81cd03b9c41d41d9", GitTreeState:"clean"}
**Server Version**: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With v1.2 Kubernetes we use `ReplicaSet` (a newer form of `ReplicationController`).  Given that you have a `ReplicaSet`, you must have used a v1.2 client to create it.  But it doesn't stop there.  What 1.2 actually creates for you is a `Deployment` which itself manages `ReplicaSets`.

So what you need to know is `kubectl scale deployment` or `kubectl delete deployment`.

Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: Thank you for the information! Most of the information is coming from http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide, and some from "Kubernetes up and Running". Basically looking for information wherever I can find it ;)