# Can't delete strangely numbered pod or mysteriously created ReplicaSet

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am having this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138636/how-do-i-delete-orphan-kubernetes-pods) except I have not created a ReplicaSet as suggested by [Tim Hockin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3653449/tim-hockin).

Somehow a ReplicaSet was created with the same properties as my ReplicationController. The only difference is the name.  The Controller is named 'fp-frontend' and the Set is named 'fp-frontend-389969098'. The appended number suggests that it was automatically created.

Perhaps a race condition or something, who knows.... I would however like to delete it and the pods it spawns.

So I try to delete it:

`$kubectl delete rs fp-frontend-389969098
replicaset "fp-frontend-389969098" deleted`

Command says it was deleted. But...

`$kubectl get rs
NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
fp-frontend-389969098   1         1         4s`

Any suggestions?
I think I am going to delete and recreate the cluster?

I am using google container engine and kubernetes is up to date.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably created a deployment that's recreating the replica set for you. Try running `kubectl get deployments` and deleting the deployment from the output of that command.