# GKE Kubernetes Node Pool Upgrade very slow

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am experimenting with GKE cluster upgrades in a 6 nodes (in two node pools) test cluster before I try it on our staging or production cluster. Upgrading when I only had a 12 replicas nginx deployment, the nginx ingress controller and cert-manager (as helm chart) installed took 10 minutes per node pool (3 nodes). I was very satisfied. I decided to try again with something that looks more like our setup. I removed the nginx deploy and added 2 node.js deployments, the following helm charts: mongodb-0.4.27, mcrouter-0.1.0 (as a statefulset), redis-ha-2.0.0, and my own www-redirect-0.0.1 chart (simple nginx which does redirect). The problem seems to be with mcrouter. Once the node starts draining, the status of that node changes to `Ready,SchedulingDisabled` (which seems normal) but the following pods remains:

- mcrouter-memcached-0
- fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-4f87t
- kube-proxy-gke-test-upgrade-cluster-default-pool-74f8edac-wblf

I do not know why those two kube-system pods remains, but that mcrouter is mine and it won't go quickly enough. If I wait long enough (1 hour+) then it eventually work, I am not sure why.  The current node pool (of 3 nodes) started upgrading 2h46 minutes ago and 2 nodes are upgraded, the 3rd one is still upgrading but nothing is moving... I presume it will complete in the next 1-2 hours...
I tried to run the drain command with `--ignore-daemonsets --force` but it told me it was already drained.
I tried to delete the pods, but they just come back and the upgrade does not move any faster.
Any thoughts?

## Update #1

The mcrouter helm chart was installed like this:

`helm install stable/mcrouter --name mcrouter --set controller=statefulset`

The statefulsets it created for mcrouter part is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mcrouter-mcrouter
    chart: mcrouter-0.1.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: mcrouter
  name: mcrouter-mcrouter
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mcrouter-mcrouter
      chart: mcrouter-0.1.0
      heritage: Tiller
      release: mcrouter
  serviceName: mcrouter-mcrouter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mcrouter-mcrouter
        chart: mcrouter-0.1.0
        heritage: Tiller
        release: mcrouter
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app: mcrouter-mcrouter
                release: mcrouter
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - args:
        - -p 5000
        - --config-file=/etc/mcrouter/config.json
        command:
        - mcrouter
        image: jphalip/mcrouter:0.36.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: mcrouter-port
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: mcrouter-mcrouter
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: mcrouter-port
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: mcrouter-port
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 256m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/mcrouter
          name: config
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: mcrouter-mcrouter
        name: config
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
```

and here is the memcached statefulset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mcrouter-memcached
    chart: memcached-1.2.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: mcrouter
  name: mcrouter-memcached
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 5
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mcrouter-memcached
      chart: memcached-1.2.1
      heritage: Tiller
      release: mcrouter
  serviceName: mcrouter-memcached
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mcrouter-memcached
        chart: memcached-1.2.1
        heritage: Tiller
        release: mcrouter
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app: mcrouter-memcached
                release: mcrouter
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - command:
        - memcached
        - -m 64
        - -o
        - modern
        - -v
        image: memcached:1.4.36-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: memcache
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: mcrouter-memcached
        ports:
        - containerPort: 11211
          name: memcache
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: memcache
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 64Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
status:
  replicas: 0
```

Comment: Can you share a configuration of your `mcrouter-memcached-0` statefulset deployment?

Comment: @AntonKostenko Sure thing! I updated my question above. Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: you paste 2 StatefulSet, but mark second as a replicaset:)

Comment: @AntonKostenko The helm chart created 2 statefulsets, the one you asked for is the second one, yes. Thanks :)

Comment: @AntonKostenko Oh, I get what you mean now, I fixed my question! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a combination of the minAvailable value from a PodDisruptionBudget (that was part of the memcached helm chart which is a dependency of the mcrouter helm chart) and the replicas value for the memcached replicaset. Both were set to 5 and therefore none of them could be deleted during the drain. I tried changing the minAvailable to 4 but [PDB are immutable at this time](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45398). What I did was remove the helm chart and replace it.

```
helm delete --purge myproxy
helm install ./charts/mcrouter-0.1.0-croy.1.tgz --name myproxy --set controller=statefulset --set memcached.replicaCount=5 --set memcached.pdbMinAvailable=4
```

Once that was done, I was able to get the cluster to upgrade normally.

What I should have done (but only thought about it after) was to change the replicas value to 6, this way I would not have needed to delete and replace the whole chart.

Thank you @AntonKostenko for trying to help me finding this issue.
This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122841/kubectl-drain-not-evicting-helm-memcached-pods) also helped me.
Thanks to the folks in [Slack@Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.slack.com), specially to Paris who tried to get my issue more visibility and the volonteers of the [Kubernetes Office Hours](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/events/office-hours.md) (which happened to be [yesterday](https://youtu.be/9S6GB_rVySU?t=36m38s), lucky me!) for also taking a look.
Finally, thank you to psycotica0 from [Kubernetes Canada](https://k8scanada.slack.com) to also give me some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

That is a bit complex question and I am definitely not sure that it is like how I thinking, but... Let's try to understand what is happening.

You have an upgrade process and have 6 nodes in the cluster. The system will upgrade it one by one using Drain to remove all workload from the pod.

Drain process itself respecting your settings and number of replicas and **desired state** of workload has **higher priority** than the drain of the node itself.

During the drain process, Kubernetes will try to schedule all your workload on resources where scheduling available. Scheduling on a node which system want to drain is disabled, you can see it in its state - `Ready,SchedulingDisabled`.

So, Kubernetes scheduler trying to find a right place for your workload on all available nodes. It will wait as long as it needs to place everything you describe in a cluster configuration.

Now the most important thing. You set that you need `replicas: 5` for your `mcrouter-memcached`. It cannot run more than one replica per node because of `podAntiAffinity` and a node for a running it should have enough resources for that, which is calculated using `resources:` block of `ReplicaSet`.

So, I think, that your cluster just does not has enough resource for a run new replica of `mcrouter-memcached` on the remaining 5 nodes. As an example, on the last node where a replica of it still not running, you have not enough memory because of other workloads.

I think if you will set `replicaset` for `mcrouter-memcached` to 4, it will solve a problem. Or you can try to use a bit more powerful instances for that workload, or add one more node to the cluster, it also should help.

Hope I gave enough explanation of my logic, ask me if something not clear to you. But first please try to solve an issue by provided solution:)

Comment: Ah, thank you. That is a super clear explanation, I will try what you suggest and get back to you before accepting the answer.

Comment: @roychri so, is it ok now? Did you fix an issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly, this did not help. I changed the replicas from 5 to 3 and it still wouldn't upgrade on its own. I think my situation is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122841/kubectl-drain-not-evicting-helm-memcached-pods

Comment: Did you started an update process from scratch, or just changed it during a current working? For fix one node you can just delete pods from it manually, after you changed replicas.

Comment: The upgrade eventually goes thru, after GKE waited an hour for a node, it forces it. So I had to start a new upgrade since the previous one had completed (but took a while, 1 hour per node!)